# Apply fullscreen or change application theme to whole application with preferences

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-styles

#### *How to Apply Fullscreen or any theme to application with Preference Activity directly with optimized steps?*

Created application perference screen with <kbd>Preference Activity</kbd> with various application settings option applied to whole application.

Layout of Preference Screen :- res/xml/settings.xml

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/appearance" >
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="prefIsFullScreen"
        android:summary="@string/fullscreen_summary"
        android:title="@string/fullscreen" >
    </CheckBoxPreference>
  </PerferenceCategory>
<PreferenceScreen>
```

What I tried: Works like butter

To apply  `Fullscreen` to whole application.

From `onOptionSelected` of `Activity`

startActivityForResult(this,PreferenceSettingsActivity.class)

After checking checkbox for Fullscreen option in Preference Activity.

`onActivityResult()` of start Activity, I've restarted that activity with

```
Intent i = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(i);
```

onCreate of Activity, I created below snippet to make it fullscreen on the basis of Preferences

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  pref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(SmartConsultant.getApplication());
   if(pref.getBoolean("prefIsFullScreen", false))
   {
 setTheme(R.style.FullScreen);                
     }
     setContentView(R.layout.options_screen_updated);
  }
```

This works perfectly fine. But I've so many `Activity`in my application which makes these solution bit of lengthy for me.

Anybody please guide me to make optimize solution for applying theme to application with little changes in application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a superclass for your activities, put the if statement for theme in the super class. Each activity then extends that super class instead of Activity directly.

Super class will only require the onCreate method. Then each activity only needs

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.options_screen_updated);
}
```

Super class has

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  pref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(SmartConsultant.getApplication());
  if(pref.getBoolean("prefIsFullScreen", false))
  {
    setTheme(R.style.FullScreen);                
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm already extending `FragmentActivity` but the way you pointing is not a bad option either.Lemme implement it then. Thanks for your suggestion.